# How to pass main query column value to nested sub query Where condition?

Tags: c#-4.0, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am writing this query with nested subquery to find `PREPARED_BY`, `VERIFIED_BY`, `AUTHORIZED_BY` depending on `CONDATE` from `Expenditure` table, but in my sub query the `Expenditure` table object `CONDATE` is not recognized and throws this error :

> ORA-00904: "EX"."CONDATE": invalid identifier.

Code:

```
SELECT ex.conno,
       ex.itemno,
       ex.adv_no || ' ' || to_char(ex.condate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') chequenodate,
       ex.conname,
       ex.apaid,
       ex.dpayment,
       gf.gf_name,
       expenditure_type,
       ex.off_code,
       ofc.officename,
       ex.remarks,
       (SELECT prepared_by
        FROM   (SELECT prepared_by
                FROM   authorization
                WHERE  (pre_last_date >= ex.condate OR pre_last_date IS NULL)
                AND    project_id = 128
                ORDER  BY id ASC)
        WHERE  rownum = 1) AS prepared_by,
       (SELECT verified_by
        FROM   (SELECT verified_by
                FROM   authorization
                WHERE  (ve_last_date >= ex.condate OR ve_last_date IS NULL)
                AND    project_id = 128
                ORDER  BY id ASC)
        WHERE  rownum = 1) AS verified_by,
       (SELECT authorized_by
        FROM   (SELECT authorized_by
                FROM   authorization
                WHERE  (au_last_date >= ex.condate OR au_last_date IS NULL)
                AND    project_id = 128
                ORDER  BY id ASC)
        WHERE  rownum = 1) AS authorized_by

FROM   expenditure ex
INNER  JOIN officecode ofc
ON     ofc.off_code = ex.off_code
INNER  JOIN coa_category ca
ON     ca.coa_cat_id = ex.coa_cat_id
INNER  JOIN g_fund_type gf
ON     gf.gf_type_id = ca.gf_type_id
WHERE  ex.conno = 'MGSP/PMU/NON/145'
AND    ex.itemno = 149;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're experiencing is that parent table can only be referenced by a subquery one level down. You're trying to access columns from the parent table in the subquery two levels down, hence why you're getting the error.

In order to access the parent column in your subquery, you're going to need to rewrite it so that it's only one level down.

This can be achieved by using the [`KEEP FIRST/LAST`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions#first_and_last) aggregate function, e.g.:

```
SELECT ex.conno,
       ex.itemno,
       ex.adv_no || ' ' || to_char(ex.condate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') chequenodate,
       ex.conname,
       ex.apaid,
       ex.dpayment,
       gf.gf_name,
       expenditure_type,
       ex.off_code,
       ofc.officename,
       ex.remarks,
       (SELECT MAX(a.prepared_by) KEEP (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY a.id ASC)
        FROM   authorizatiion a
        WHERE  (a.pre_last_date >= ex.condate OR a.pre_last_date IS NULL)
        AND     a.project_id = 128) prepared_by,
       (SELECT MAX(a.verified_by) KEEP (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY a.id ASC)
        FROM   authorizatiion a
        WHERE  (a.ve_last_date >= ex.condate OR a.ve_last_date IS NULL)
        AND     a.project_id = 128) verified_by,
       (SELECT MAX(a.authorized_by) KEEP (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY a.id ASC)
        FROM   authorizatiion a
        WHERE  (a.au_last_date >= ex.condate OR a.au_last_date IS NULL)
        AND     a.project_id = 128) authorized_by
FROM   expenditure ex
       INNER JOIN officecode ofc ON ofc.off_code = ex.off_code
       INNER JOIN coa_category ca ON ca.coa_cat_id = ex.coa_cat_id
       INNER JOIN g_fund_type gf ON gf.gf_type_id = ca.gf_type_id
WHERE  ex.conno = 'MGSP/PMU/NON/145'
AND    ex.itemno = 149;
```

N.B. I have used `MAX` and `FIRST` here; this means that if there are multiple rows with the same lowest id, the highest value of the prepared_by column will be used. You could change this to `MIN` if you wanted the lowest value. This is only relevant if you have more than one row per id, otherwise it simply returns the value of the prepared_by column for the lowest id.